# How to solve "QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded"

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite, qt, qsqldatabase

I'm trying to create a Qt interface to connect to a MySQL database but it's giving me an error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

this is my code:

```cpp
QSqlDatabase db1 = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db1.setHostName("localhost");
db1.setUserName("root");
db1.setPassword("");
db1.setDatabaseName("journal_machine");
```

This is my configuration:

- Qt Creator 2.8.1
- Qt 5.1.1 (MSVC2010 , 32bit)
- Windows 10 64 bit
- MySQL 5.6.17 installed with WampServer 2.5 (64bit)

Comment: Is the libmysql.dll in your PATH? Are the Qt plugins in your PATH?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QMYSQL driver loading error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821329/qmysql-driver-loading-error)

Comment: i have MySQL 5.6 installed on 
` C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17 `
and i have `libmysql.dll` in `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\lib`

@OnWhenReady what should i do exactly !!

Comment: As a first attempt: Put the dll in the directory of the executable.

Comment: i did past `libmysql.dll` 
 in 

`C:\Users\Amine\Documents\QT\build-Journal_Machine-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug`

`Journal_Machine.exe
journal_machine.o
libmysql.dll
libmysqld.dll
main.o
moc_journal_machine.cpp
moc_journal_machine.o`
But still the same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

It's late to answer, but this may be useful for future readers.

For *project kit 64 bit* use *MySql 64 bit*, and for *project kit 32 bit* use *MySql 32 bit*.

note: xx: 64 or 32

- `qsqlmysql.dll` and `qsqlmysqld.dll` files should be exist in `<QtDir>\mingw73_xx\plugins\sqldrivers` folder.
- `libqsqlmysql.a` and `libqsqlmysqld.a` files should be exist in `<QtDir>\mingw73_xx\lib` folder.
- libmysql.dll file should be exist in `<QtDir>\mingw73_xx\bin` folder.

Now, you can build your project.

// comment:

If "QMYSQL driver not loaded" error persists, follow instrument:

1. Copy MySql folder from Program Files to a simple path. (for example: "D:/MySQL")
2. Go to "\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql" folder
3. Open mysql.pro as text.
4. Comment `QMAKE_USE += mysql` line using '#'. (`#QMAKE_USE += mysql`)
5. Add following lines after that:

   `LIBS += 'D:/MySQL/lib/libmysql.lib'`

   `INCLUDEPATH += 'D:/MySQL/include'`

   `DEPENDPATH += 'D:/MySQL/include'`
6. Save file.
7. Open `Qt 5.13.1 (MinGW 7.3.0 xx-bit).exe` from start menu (for example).
8. Go to `<QtDir>\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers` folder (use 'cd' command).
9. Use `qmake mysql.pro` command.
10. Use `mingw32-make` command.
11. If compile done successfully, go to `<QtDir>\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\plugins\sqldrivers` folder.
12. Copy `qsqlmysql.dll` and `qsqlmysqld.dll` files into `<QtDir>\mingw73_xx\plugins\sqldrivers` folder.
13. Copy `libqsqlmysql.a` and `libqsqlmysqld.a` files into `<QtDir>\mingw73_xx\lib` folder.

// comment:

If error persists, follow instrument:

1. Download "MySQL Connector C 6.1" program and install it.
2. Go to `<MySQL Connector C 6.1 Dir>\bin` folder.
3. Copy `libmysql.dll` file into `<QtDir>\mingw73_xx\bin` folder.

Comment: Copying libmysql.dll (from Windows Mysql Community Server/lib) to the app-folder, in addition to the DIY qsqlmysql.dll... that was the hint I needed! Thx.

Comment: You're welcome.