# QMYSQL driver not loaded (other solution?)

Tags: mysql, windows, qt

I was having this problem where I couldn't connect with MySQL database. However [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821329/qmysql-driver-loading-error) answer worked out for me. the problem is: I don't want to copy and paste "libmysql.dll" and "libmysql.lib" into every project that uses MySQL (as stated by "Basti Vagabond").

Is there any other way to fix this problem?

Keep in mind that my case is exactly like the one in the link above.

Comment: Welcome to the fantastic world of shared libraries on Windows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options to automate this process:

One way would be to add the library path to your `main.cpp`.

```
qApp->addLibraryPath( "C:\\path\\something\\mysql.dll" );
```

---

Or you automate the whole process:

[From Qt Docs:](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html)

> **QMAKE_POST_LINK** 
>   Specifies the command to execute after linking the TARGET together. This variable is normally empty and therefore nothing is executed.

---

```
# If operating system is Windows perform this V
win32 {
    # Create variable containing the path to your project compile folder ( probably no need to change since this is automated by Qt )
    OUT_PWD_WINDOWS         = $$OUT_PWD
    # Switch frontslashes with double backslashes
    OUT_PWD_WINDOWS         ~= s,/,\\,g

    # Create variables to set debug path and release path
    # Gotta change the \\debug and \\release to the correct debug and release folders
    OUT_PWD_WINDOWS_DEBUG   = $$quote( $$OUT_PWD_WINDOWS\\debug   )
    OUT_PWD_WINDOWS_RELEASE = $$quote( $$OUT_PWD_WINDOWS\\release )

    # Create variables to set the path to libs and dlls you want to copy ( *.lib will copy all files ending in .lib from the specified path )
    # you can change that however to mysql.lib for example if you only want 1, same goes for .dll
    LIBS_TO_COPY            = $$quote( C:\\MySql\\libs\\*.lib )
    DLLS_TO_COPY            = $$quote( C:\\MySql\\libs\\*.dll )


    # Copy libraries and dlls into debug path / else copys them into the release folder
    # essentially this is saying if( config == debug ) perform tasks else perform tasks for release, which is add actions to be executed after linking
    CONFIG( debug , debug|release ) {
        # Here we add the copy command to the QMAKE_POST_LINK variable which will be executed once the linking is done
        # We have 1 entry for libs and 1 for dlls, same goes for the release which is in the else
        QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote( xcopy $$LIBS_TO_COPY $$OUT_PWD_WINDOWS_DEBUG    $$escape_expand( \n\t ) )
        QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote( xcopy $$DLLS_TO_COPY $$OUT_PWD_WINDOWS_DEBUG    $$escape_expand( \n\t ) )
    } else {
        QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote( xcopy $$LIBS_TO_COPY $$OUT_PWD_WINDOWS_RELEASE  $$escape_expand( \n\t ) )
        QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote( xcopy $$DLLS_TO_COPY $$OUT_PWD_WINDOWS_RELEASE  $$escape_expand( \n\t ) )
    }
}
```

Now rename / remove your build folder, put this in your `.pro` file, make the path adjustments and you can paste this into all of your `.pro` files to have those libraries supplied to where you need them.

You can even automate that by creating a macro / keybind / snippet that you load into your `.pro` files.

---

Side note:
For other operating systems you'll have to write this with the OS specific command

---

Compiler output:

```
xcopy C:\Actions\*.lib C:\Users\xyz\dev\C++\Qt\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\debug
C:\Actions\Test - Copy (2).lib
C:\Actions\Test - Copy.lib
C:\Actions\Test.lib
3 File(s) copied
xcopy C:\Actions\*.dll C:\Users\xyz\dev\C++\Qt\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\debug
C:\Actions\test - Copy (2).dll
C:\Actions\test - Copy.dll
C:\Actions\test.dll
3 File(s) copied
01:45:08: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
```

Comment: in the first case, isn't it necessary to do this in every program? returning to the source of the problem, which is "How to use MySQL without copying and pasting code everytime".

Comment: Also, the second option looks great.... but I didn't understand much of it. Can you explain a little further? I am relatively new. `win32{}` is suppose to be in Qt cmd or the project itself?

Comment: @andseg i'll edit it once i can to make some things more clear, but the whole package is supposed to be in your .pro

Comment: @andseg as peppe already pointed out you don't have a lot of options, so I simply provided you with one you can keep as snippet and simply load in once you need `QMYSQL` I made some adjustments to tell you more specifically what what does in the code. Again this block goes into your project file `YourProject.pro` for example.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time in explaining it even further. I see my options are limited but it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much you can do -- Windows searches for `.dll`s in a handful of places, all of which are terrible for shared libraries coming from different places (just think of what happens if more than one application wants to install its own copy/version of them):

Quoting from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18(v=vs.140).aspx :

> With both implicit and explicit linking, Windows first searches for "known DLLs", such as Kernel32.dll and User32.dll. Windows then searches for the DLLs in the following sequence:
>
> 1. The directory where the executable module for the current process is located.
> 2. The current directory.
> 3. The Windows system directory. The GetSystemDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
> 4. The Windows directory. The GetWindowsDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
> 5. The directories listed in the PATH environment variable.

You were doing 1., which is the only sensible thing to do.

On your user on your system, you could also just use 5. and modify PATH (but this doesn't work if you want to create deployable packages!).

2., 3. and 4. are totally useless for application developers.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. but why 5. doesn't work for deployable packages?

Comment: Because you don't want to modify the user's PATH when installing your application. What happens if *another* application with an incompatible mysql DLL gets installed too?