# QMYSQL - driver not loaded

Tags: mysql, qt, qt-creator

OS: Windows 10 x64

I've updated my Qt version from `5.10.0` to `5.12.5`. I had a bit of trouble getting my kits to work again but eventually I could qmake and build the application. But as soon as I start it, the Application Output log tells me "driver not loaded". Usually I fixed this by putting a `libmysql.dll` that my co-worker sent me in the root directory of the executable. But now (I think due to a version mismatch) this method won't work anymore.
I've just about tried anything. I re-installed MySQL, followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31844328/8602926), I tried locating the .dll's, I've even tried building the MySQL libraries by myself but none of that worked out.
The `plugins\sqldrivers` folder of all of my compilers only contain these .dll's but not `mysql.dll`:

[image]

> What am I doing wrong / What did you people do to make MySQL work?

Answer (score 0):

I use `5.12.5` too,but I build mysql driver successfully.Here is what I do:

1. Get src of Qt
2. Open the `mysql.pro`.In my computer the path is:`C:\Qt\Qt5.12.5\5.12.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql`
3. Find your `mysql` path,in my computer is `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0`.Because it has `space` so I copy the `include` and `lib` to `D:\mysql\`
4. Change the `mysql.pro` using `QtCreator`

```cpp
TARGET = qsqlmysql

HEADERS += $$PWD/qsql_mysql_p.h
SOURCES += $$PWD/qsql_mysql.cpp $$PWD/main.cpp

#QMAKE_USE += mysql

OTHER_FILES += mysql.json

PLUGIN_CLASS_NAME = QMYSQLDriverPlugin

win32:LIBS += -LD:/mysql/lib/ -llibmysql
INCLUDEPATH += D:/mysql/include
DEPENDPATH += D:/mysql/include


include(../qsqldriverbase.pri)
```

I change `#QMAKE_USE += mysql` and add

```
win32:LIBS += -LD:/mysql/lib/ -llibmysql
INCLUDEPATH += D:/mysql/include
DEPENDPATH += D:/mysql/include
```

You should change the `win32:LIBS` `INCLUDEPATH` `DEPENDPATH` to your path.

5. I click the `Run` and I get a `window`,click `cancle`.
6. Because my `Qt` is in `C:/` so I find `C:\plugins\sqldrivers\`,I get `qsqlmysql.dll` and `qsqlmysqld.dll` and I copy them to `C:\Qt\Qt5.12.5\5.12.5\mingw73_64\plugins\sqldrivers`
7. I download `mysql-connector-c` from [here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-c/) and copy it to `C:\Qt\Qt5.12.5\5.12.5\mingw73_64\bin`

After I do these works I can connect mysql.Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer but I don't have a `mysql.pro` file in `qtbase\src\plugins`

Comment: I am sure it is in `Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql`.Are you sure you install the `Sources` when you install `Qt`? If you don't you can install it using `MaintenanceTool` or download from [here](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.12/5.12.5/single/) You can find the `mysql.pro` from the file.

Comment: If you download the `qt-everywhere-src-5.12.5` ,don't move anything ,just `unzip` the `zip` or `tar.xz` and open the `mysql.pro`. I try to move the `sqldirvers` folder to other place and I got bug. If it still not work,try to get other way or install `5.12.3`,just need to move `C connector`

Comment: That might be it actually. Tomorrow I'll be working on this project again so I'll make sure to get a sysadmin to install the sources. Thanks in advance!